# C compiler Warning

Tags: c

I have a very general question, when i tried to write a character array to a file, I wrote the code as

```
fwrite(array[10],1,10,file_ptr)
```

and the compiler threw a warning `argument 1 makes from integer to pointer without a cast.`

Then I modified the line as

```
fwrite(&array[10],1,10,file_ptr)
```

and the warning doesnt show up any more now.

Question : How does the compiler differentiate between address and value?  What if the value at `array[10]` resembles a proper address?

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of `array`?

Answer (score 4):

If you have an array of ten characters, i.e.

```
char array[10];
```

then doing `array[10]` accesses the *eleventh* element of that array.

Simply pass the array variable, it works as a pointer:

```
fwrite(array, 1, 10, file);
```

Comment: +1 because you pointed out the error, "works as pointer" is rather "decays into a pointer", though.

Answer (score 1):

C is a *statically typed* language. Whenever you write

```
char array[100];
```

you are telling the C compiler that `array` is an array of 100 characters. Then, it knows that `array[10]` is a character, and that `&array[10]` is a pointer to a character (a `char *`).

`fwrite`, though, is defined as taking a `const void *` as its first parameter, i.e. an untyped pointer. If you pass it something that's not a pointer, the compiler knows this and will complain.

Your C compiler will not try to "guess" what the type of something is based on its value.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `fwrite()` is : `fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE *fptr)`.

`fwrite()` is expecting an address(or a pointer-variable that holds the address, aka pointer) and not a character, but, 
`a[10]` is a character, not a pointer. Which is the reason for the warning!

`&a[10]` **is** an address, a valid fit as the first argument to `fwrite()`. Hence no warnings are thrown!

---

How it holds information is in its lexer+parser combination and semantic analyzer in a table called "symbol table" .

-- After the edit in the question --

`fwrite(&array[10],1,10,file_ptr)` <- argument-1 is interpreted as a string starting from 11th location in `array`

Comment: An address is not necessarily 4 bytes wide and it has nothing to do with the problem. And you don't need to mention lexers and parsers either.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze I mentioned all this because of `How does the compiler differentiate between address and value? What if the value at array[10] resembles a proper address?`

Comment: The compiler keeps track of the variable types and that's enough for one to know.

Comment: I thought I'd rather answer slightly more deep.

Comment: You can do that, but your explanation of the warning is wrong, which is why I awarded a -1 to the answer.

Comment: ah @AlexeyFrunze let me modify my answer to explain the warning.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze changed my answer

Comment: In addition to AlexeyFrunze's advice, fwrite expects a `const void *` as it's first argument (*not* a `const char *`). The char value, though only 1 byte wide will be converted to a `const void *`, which is `sizeof (const void *)` bytes wide.

Comment: Still wrong. "For fwrite() anything other than a const void * is used, it ... decides to throw a warning." Any pointer to object will be implicitly converted to a `const void *` without a warning thrown. "... argument-1 is interpreted as a string..." No, it isn't. See this manual: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fwrite.html

Comment: @modifiablelvalue reminiscent of the older answer.

Comment: No, it isn't. You can provide an `int *`, or a `char *`, or even a `kitchen_sink *` as the first argument without explicit conversion (*casting*), and without any warnings being thrown. This is because the type is `const void *` and C implicitly converts from *any pointer to object* to a pointer to void. Your original answer didn't say this. fwrite writes *objects*, not necessarily *strings*. It only writes strings if you tell it to.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue no! `fwrite()` writes `bytes`(unsigned char) starting at the address in the first variable. It does not write `objects`

Comment: Are you trying to tell me that fwrite doesn't write *objects*, but it does write *bytes*? A byte is a type of object. Have you considered arguing with your C11 standard draft?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are under the impression that `array[10]` designates the whole array--it doesn't. It designates the eleventh element of `array`, which doesn't exist (under the assumption you declared it as `some_type array[10]`).

Since you say you want to write the whole array, you need to pass fwrite() the address of the first element of `array`, which happens to be just `array` (or `&array[0]`), since in C, the name of an array when used in an expression, is the address of its first element (with the exception of the `sizeof` operator).

The compiler has complete information about types of arrays and element types so it can detect when you write an expression of type `int` in a place where a pointer is required.

There is a way to fwrite() a complete array, independent of size and element type, just using the array identifier:

```
fwrite (array, sizeof *array, sizeof array/sizeof *array, file);
```

where `sizeof *array` evaluates to the element size and `sizeof array/sizeof *array` evaluates to the number of elements in the array. Note that this works **only** for arrays, not for pointers. The same could be achieved with

```
fwrite (array, sizeof array, 1, file);
```

or

```
fwrite (array, 1, sizeof array, file);
```

It is mostly a matter of style which you prefer; they are all equivalent and will execute with identical speed.

Answer (score 0):

> What if the value at array[10] resembles a proper address?

Then your array type would have been `int (*)[n]`, and not `int [n]`. This is why we have a type system.